# How to do hasKeys() in PHP Mockery, or create custom parameter expectations?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, mockery

Mockery has a method hasKey(), which checks if a given parameter has a certain key. I want to make sure that the passed array has multiple keys. I would also like to assert that the array has x amount of elements.

Is there a built-in way to allow for custom parameter expectations? I tried using a closure that returns true or false based on the given parameter, but that didn't work.

Thanks.

Edit:

Example

```
$obj = m::mock('MyClass');
$obj->shouldReceive('method')->once()->with(m::hasKey('mykeyname'));
```

What I'm trying to do is to have more insight into what is passed to the method using `with()`. I want to assert that an array passed to a method has both key `a` AND key `b`. It would be great if I could use a closure somehow to create my own assertion, such as counting the number of array elements.

Comment: You should add a code example to visualize what you're trying to get. And what testing framework do you use?

Comment: I've updating my questions, thanks. I'm using PHPunit, somehow forgot to mention that.

Comment: Why is it important to have those keys in your test? Does the method have an error handling for missing keys? Did you make another test for the case where expected keys are missing?

Without seeing the method itself, it is hard to see if you need a technical solution like the first answer of malte offers or if you need to rethink your test or even the method because of complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can user a custom matcher.

Out of the top of my head (not tested) this could look something like this:

```
class HasKeysMatcher extends \Mockery\Matcher\MatcherAbstract
{
    protected $expectedNumberOfElements;
    public function __construct($expectedKeys, $expectedNumberOfElements)
    {
        parent::__construct($expectedKeys);
        $this->expectedNumberOfElements =$expectedNumberOfElements;
    }

    public function match(&$actual)
    {
        foreach($this->_expected as $expectedKey){
            if (!array_key_exists($expectedKey, $actual)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return $this->expectedNumberOfElements==count($actual);
    }

    /**
     * Return a string representation of this Matcher
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return '<HasKeys>';
    }

}
```

and then use it like this:

`$obj = m::mock('MyClass');
$obj->shouldReceive('method')->once()->with(new HasKeysMatcher(array('key1','key2'),5));`

Comment: thank you for great answer. I am implementing this and have one suggestion: method `hasKeys()` should be semantically similar to `hasKey()`. In original implementation of `hasKey()` matcher: `public function match(&$actual)
    {
        return in_array($this->_expected, array_keys($actual));
    }`  elements of hash array with NULL value  would return true (as `hasKey()` suggests. Whereas in your code you use `isset()` which would return false upon array with valid key but NULL value. I suggest changing `!isset($actual[$expectedKey])` to `!array_key_exists($expectedKey, $actual)`.

Comment: Spot on observation, now that you mention it I remember being tripped up by that once...

I have edited the code as you suggested, thanks...!